# ajax request internal server error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Everything is working good on local but when i try same codes in production, i get 500 (Internal Server Error) error. And also i need advices to refactor this code.

**entries.controller**

```
 def set_spam
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    @entry.spam = params[:what] == "spam" ? true : false
    @entry.save         
    respond_to do |format|
            format.js 
     end        
 end
```

**application.js**

```
  $(".spams img").click(function () {
    $.post("/set-spam", { entry_id: $(this).attr("entry_id"), what: $(this).attr("class") } );
    return false;
  });
```

**view**

```
<div class="spams">
<img title="spam" class="spam" src="/images/pixel.gif" entry_id="<%= entry.id %>" />
</div>
```

**route**

```
post "/set-spam" => "entries#set_spam"
```

Comment: What do you think you need to re-factor and why? Also put that in a separate question as it's not really related to your 500 issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check out mongrel/bricks log. Can be anything starting from permissions on a file execution.

Comment: I think the file permissions is probably the culprit, you will also want to ensure that the file you are trying to reach is also on your production host.